# making only one of the running threads to execute a catch block?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a multi threaded Java program and at times it throws an exception which requires some changes to my network settings. The problem I'm facing is that all the running threads try to do it, which causes problems. Is there a way to make only one of the running threads to execute the code in the catch block?

This is my catch block

```
        catch (ElementNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Element not found!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            IpManager.changeDSLIp();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can you use a lock? A semaphore?

Comment: *Possibly* can we see your code please? You might need a Finite State Machine, or just a synchronized block...

Comment: synchronized function or block please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Define a variable to indicate network settings has been done.
public static boolean NETWORK_SETTINGS_DONE = false;

public static Object LOCK = new Object();

public void doSometing() {
    try {

    } catch (Exception e) {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            if (!NETWORK_SETTINGS_DONE) {
                //do some changes to your network settings.
                NETWORK_SETTINGS_DONE=true;                               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would need to set NETWORK_SETTINGS_DONE back to false some time after the catch is done right? in case if the problem arises again and the catch block would need re-executing

Comment: correct. everyone (including myself) suggested static objects. you are actually better off using objects which are local to the context of your group of threads, but not truely static. this way you could have multiple thread "groups" running independently and correctly. Also, as these would be initialised at the "start" of your operation, the "done" bool would be initialised as false, rather than needing to be reset.

Comment: yes，if the network settings operations failed, NETWORK_SETTINGS_DONE should still be false.

Answer (score 0):

You need a single central service to handle the change to the network settings so you can prevent multiple changes at the same time and still give reasonable feedback. Your threads or more specific your exception handling code needs to transfer the responsibility to this service and may use it to check the current status to handle the exception in an appropriate way (sounds like the threads would have to wait for new settings).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do the trick...

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    synchronized (someCommonObject) {
        if (!done) {
            // do stuff
        }
        done = true;
    }
}
```

someCommonObject could be "this" but only if all threads are being handled by that object. otherwise pick some other (possibly static) object. The "done" boolean would have to be static  / commonly referenced also.